# How to get substrings on both sides of hyphen and trailing substring?

Tags: php, string, delimiter, substring

I am currently working on a web app which is using a specific string to call a function.  Here is a sample string:

```
$string = "translate from-to word for translate"
```

First I need to validate the string, and it should be like the above `$string`. How should I validate the string?

Then I need to extract 3 substrings from `$string`.

- The word that precedes the hyphen. (To be named: `$target`)
- The word that follows the hyphen. (To be named: `$source`)
- The text (not including the first space) that follows `$source` to the end of the string. (To be named: `$translate`)

This is my coding attempt to get the `from` and `to`:

```
$found = false;
$source ="";
$target = "";
$next = 3;
$prev = 1;
for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++){
    if($found== false){
        if($string[$i] == "-"){
            $found = true;
            while($string[$i+$prev] != " "){
                $target .= $string[$i+$prev];
                $prev +=1;
            }
            /*$next -=1;
            while($string[$i-$next] != " " && $next > 0){
                $source .= $string[$i-$next];
                $next -=1;
            }*/
        }
    }
}
```

From that code, I only can return the `$target` which contains `to` after `-`.
I don't know how to get `$source`.

Please show me the fastest way to get the `from` as `$source` and `to` as `$target`.

Then I need to get `word for translate` (all of the string after `from-to`).

So the result should be

```
$target = "to";
$source = "from";
$translate = "word for translate";
```

Finally, if the `$string` has two hyphens, like `translate from-to from-to test-test word for translate`, it should be `return false`;

**note** `to` and `from` are random strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following possible input strings:

- `translate from-to word for translate`  (1 hyphen, no accents or non-English characters)
- `translate dari-ke dari-ke word for translate`  (2 hyphens)
- `translate clé-solution word for translate`  (1 hyphen, accented character used)
- `translate goodbye-さようなら word for translate`  (1 hyphen , Japanese characters used)

A case-insensitive pattern like: `/^[a-z]+? ([a-z]+)-([a-z]+?) ([a-z ]+)$/i` will perform as requested on the first two sample strings with high efficiency, but not the last two.

Using the "word character" (`\w`) to match the substrings (instead of case-insensitive `[a-z]`) will perform as intended with the first two samples with, but also allows `0-9` and `_` as valid characters. This means a slight drop in pattern accuracy (this may be of no noticeable consequence to your project).

If you are translating strings that may go beyond English characters, it can be simpler / more forgiving to use a "negated character class" for matching.  If you want to allow letters beyond `a-z`, like accented and other multibyte characters, then `[^-]` will offer a broad allowance of characters (at the expense of allowing many unwanted letters too).  Here is [a demo of this kind of pattern](https://regex101.com/r/olWZSR/1).

It is important to only write "capture groups" for substrings that you want to subsequently use.  For this reason, I do not capture the leading substring `translate`.

`list()` is a handy "language construct" to assign variable names to array values.  Notice that the first element (the fullstring match) is not assigned to a variable.  This is why `list()`'s parameters starts with `,`. If you don't wish to leverage the convenience of `list()`, then you can manually assign the three variable names over three lines like this:

```
$source=$out[1];
$target=$out[2];
$translate=$out[3];
```

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/70b66e736ee3e56e5dad0861cfc65d40d75e1cdb))

```
$strings=[
    "translate from-to word for translate",
    "translate dari-ke dari-ke word for translate",
    "translate clé-solution word for translate",
    "translate goodbye-さようなら word for translate"
];

foreach($strings as $string){
    if(preg_match('/^[a-z]+? ([^-]+)-([^-]+?) ([a-z ]+)$/i',$string,$out)){
        list(,$source,$target,$translate)=$out;
        echo "source=$source; target=$target; translate=$translate";
    }else{
        var_export(false);  // $found=false;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
source=from; target=to; translate=word for translate
false
source=clé; target=solution; translate=word for translate
source=goodbye; target=さようなら; translate=word for translate
```

---

While regex provides a much more concise method with fewer function calls, this is a non-regex method:

```
if(substr_count($string,'-')!=1){
    var_export(false);  // $found=false;
}else{
    $trimmed=ltrim($string,'translate ');
    $array=explode(' ',$trimmed,2);
    list($source,$target)=explode('-',$array[0]);
    $translate=$array[1];
    echo "source=$source; target=$target; translate=$translate";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, this can be done with a [regular expression](http://php.net/preg-match):

```
<?php
$string = "translate from-to word for translate";
$result = preg_match("/^([\w ]+?) (\w+)-(\w+) ([\w ]+)$/", $string, $matches);
if ($result) {
    print_r($matches);
    $source = $matches[2];
    $target = $matches[3];
    $translate = $matches[4];
} else {
    echo "No match";
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => translate from-to word for translate
    [1] => translate
    [2] => from
    [3] => to
    [4] => word for translate
)
```

Here is an [explanation of the regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/YwXaAo/1).

Comment: can you help me if the string `translate from-to from-to test-test word for translate` it should return false